# Module requests doesn't want to install

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRCSf.png)

I reinstall python. When i installing modules i faced with this problem: "C:\Users\Danya1>pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\pythonn\lib\site-packages (2.25.1)

Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in d:\pythonn\lib\site-packages (fro
m requests) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in d:\pythonn\lib\site-packages
(from requests) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\pythonn\lib\site-package
s (from requests) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in d:\pythonn\lib\site-pack
ages (from requests) (1.26.3)"

Comment: It appears to already be installed?

Comment: Check if you have already installed some python distributions.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting means that the module is already installed, it's not that pip doesn't want to install it, it's more accurate to say pip refuses to save the same module more than once.

The following commands may help you:

1. `pip freeze` this will show the full list of modules installed and their respective version number
2. `pip list` will do the same as the first
3. `pip show <insert_module_name>` will show you exactly where the module is saved on your device
4. `pip install <insert_module_name> --upgrade` will upgrade the module to the latest version

For example, I would run `pip freeze` to see if the requests module appears, then I would run `pip show requests` to see exactly where.